# Do conserved quantities tell us more general pattern than what we are taught?

Tags: energy, kinematics, momentum, conservation-laws

Last year I had a question in m mind that as $mv$ (momentum) and $mv^2/2$ (Kinetic energy) both are conserved then n a closed system and they are dependent on same quantities and look very similar so can we say that $m(v)^3$ and $m(v)^4$ and so on will also be conserved in a closed system of particles if yes then how can we prove it more generally that if MULTIPLICATION (not addition or subtraction I have a feeling that it will not work with them correct me if I am wrong) of some number of quantities is conserved then if we just change only  power of some quantity the pattern will still remain true(here I am not talking about momentum and energy but about every conserved quantity) so for example angular momentum$(mvr)$ is conserved so can we say that tweaking power of variable will not effect the conservation law(if we take all bodies interacting with it into account) so in this case will $mv^πr$ be conserved, again I am not only talking about some perticular conserved quantity but point of my question is that if some quantity $x=abc$ which is conserved exist then will $a^pb^qc^r$ also be conserved, that is what I mean by generalisation.

It will obviously works when I increase power of the whole term like $(mv)^2$(momentum squared) or multiply term by some constant like mv/2(half momentum) and actually mass is a constant so multiplying momentum by mass $(m^2v)$ will not break the pattern but can we say this for every possible equation if not what is it's limitations?

This question is atleast useful as if we would have predicted that as mv is conserved $(mv)^2$ may also be conserved, and turns out that half of that $mv^2/2$ is a useful conserved quantity so answering this question may help us a lot

NOTE- in the kinetic energy question, assume that no non contact forces act between the particles only colliding(contact) forces act, or take the direction of movement into account like we do in momentum, then with non contact forces also kinetic energy will be conserved although that new direction dependent quantity will not be called kinetic energy also assume that no heating because of friction is happening.

Comment: Conservation of $\sum_im_iv_i,\,\sum_im_iv_i^2$ doesn't imply conservation of $\sum_im_iv_i^3$ etc. Dredge up tour favourite "calculate the outcome of this elastic collision" problem, then see it for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you just have a single particle moving in empty space, with no forces acting on it, then
$$
0 = \vec{F} = m \frac{d}{dt} \vec{v} \implies \vec{v} \text{ is const}.
$$
If the velocity is constant, then any function of the velocity $f(v)$ is also constant.
$$
\frac{d}{dt}f(v) = 0.
$$
So yes, $mv^n$ in particular is constant. However, this is just for one particle moving with no forces acting on it. The conservation of momentum really states that
$$
0 = \frac{d}{dt} \sum_i m_i \vec{v}_i.
$$
Furthermore, if the particles have forces between each other, then kinetic energy alone isn't conserved, but total energy, which is kinetic plus potential, is conserved.
$$
0 = \frac{d}{dt} \left(PE +  \sum_i m_i v_i^2 \right).
$$
There is no way to take the statements of conservation of momentum and energy and use it to prove that
$$
0 = \frac{d}{dt} \left( \sum_i m_i v_i^n \right)
$$
which is simply not true.

Edit: Even if $PE$ is zero for particles which are not in contact, i.e. is we have only contact forces, its still not true.

Comment: Yes sir, but if the don't have any non contact forces between them and are just colliding with each other so only can have contact forces between them then kinetic energy will be conserved assume that no energy conversion can take place like kinetic to potential, heat, light etc

Comment: Or take direction of kinetic energy into account like we do in momentum although we can't call that energy but a new direction dependent quantity mv^2 so m(speed^2) isn't conserved but m(velocity^2) is conserved let's call it momentum's brother

Comment: velocity squared isn't a vector

Answer (score 1):

Each conservation law comes from a symmetry principle of the underlying physics.

See Emmy Noether's theorem  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem

Comment: Certainly relevant, but doesn't directly answer the question that was posed about higher orders of $mv$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear where OP wants to take this question, but it should be said that the existence of sufficiently many conservations laws is the very hallmark of an [integrable system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system), which is an important topic in modern physics. Conversely, not every physical system is integrable.

Answer (score 0):

Given a closed system in which total kinetic energy and momentum is conserved then you have
$$\sum_{i} m_i v_i = c$$
$$\sum_{i} m_i v_i^2 = k$$
where c and k are two different constants, namely the total momentum and twice the total energy of the system. What you are thinking is that since these are equal to a constant, multiplying them together will also be a constant and so you get some sort of new (not really because it comes from the old one) conservation law like $\sum_{i} m_i^2 v_i^2 = constant$ by multiplying the first equation by itself for example. Unfortuntely unless you have only 1 term in the sum, that's not how it works. What you get when you multiply two sums is a double sum. So if you multiplied the first and second equations then you would get
$$\sum_{i} \sum_{j} m_i v_i m_j v_j^2 = ck$$
So you end up with cross terms where the index $i$ and $j$ are unequal. For example, suppose you have a two particle system. Then
$$m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2 = c$$
$$m_1 v_1^2 + m_2 v_2^2 = k$$
$$(m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2)(m_1 v_1^2 + m_2 v_2^2) = ck \neq m_1^2 v_1^3 + m_2^2 v_2^3$$
Here you would have cross terms like $m_1v_1m_2v_2^2$ and $m_2v_2m_1v_1^2$.

Comment: No that wasn't my point, my point in short is that mv is conserved then will (m^p)(v^q) also be conserved where p and q are any random powers and you don't necessarily have to derive it from momentum and kinetic energy, if they are conserved in physical experiments then it doesn't matter if they are derived from alredy well known constants

Comment: But you are trying to derive it from already well known constants when you ask *if* $mv$ is conserved whether $m^pv^q$ is conserved or not. If $m^p v^q$ really were an independent conservation law then it would not depend on whether $mv$ is conserved or not.